# How to Match values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have the following type of data I want to update the description field in `sheet 1` which are in `Col B`, `col C` and `Col D` if the `ItemID` Matches for the records in sheet 2

Sheet 1

```
   Col A     Col B       Col C          Col D      COL E    COL F
   Item ID   Item Desc   Purchase D     Sales Des   STOCK    Rev
   600111     xxxx        yyyy          zzzz         15      1
   600111     xxxx        yyyy          zzzz         15      1
   600111     xxxx        yyyy          zzzz         15      1
   600255     mmmm        nnnn          yyyy          5      2
   600224     aaaa        bbbb          cccc          5      5
   600224     aaaa        bbbb          cccc          5      5
```

Note: ColA data is copied from another Excel File. The Idea is to Update The description field

Sheet 2

```
 Col A     Col B       Col C         Col D
Item ID   Item Desc   Purchase C    Sales Des
600255      mmmm        xxxx          yyyy
600224      rrrr        sss           tttt
600111      LLLL        MMMM            nnn
```

In `Sheet 3` i want to display updated `Sheet 1` with Descriptions from `Sheet 2`

```
   Col A     Col B       Col C          Col D      COL E    COL F
   Item ID   Item Desc   Purchase D     Sales Des   STOCK    Rev
   600111     LLLL        MMMM             nnn         15      1
   600111     LLLL        MMMM             nnn         15      1
   600111     LLLL        MMMM             nnn         15      1
   600255     mmmm        xxxx             yyyy        5       2
   600224     rrrr        ssss             ttt         5       5
   600224     rrrr        ssss             ttt         5       5
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are asking only for matching here. Where do you want to sort or align in the above flow ?

Comment: @KanikeVamshiKrishna Thanks, All i want is to change the description in sheet 1 if Item ID in Sheet 1 and Sheet2 matches

Comment: If the second sheet has unique values for `Item ID`, then you can you use `vlookup` in sheets 3. Look up values for Col B,C & D from sheet 2 and for other fields just copy values from sheet 1. 
This should do the job. If you want a VBA code then do let know

Answer (score 0):

This would be a LOT easier if you decided to use punctuation, so we can tell where one sentence ends and the next one starts.

As I understand it, you are only looking for a formula or solution for Sheet3.

Try this formula in Sheet3, cell B2:

=vlookup($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1000,column(B1),false)

Copy across to Sheet3 cell C2 and D2, then copy down. Adjust the lookup range rows as per your data on sheet 2.